# Prestashop Products csv imports for addition and update

Tags: php, csv, prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.5

I am using Prestashop 1.5.4 and we get bulk product updates for suppliers frequently in form of CSV. The pre-built Prestashop import module worked great when we want to add new products to the system. However, **the problem occurred when the CSV list contains both addition and modification of existing products.**

we can update the list if there is a fixed operation with the achievable amount of products, but things get hectic when the number goes into 100s and process become repetitive.

Hence, I am looking for an automated way which could help in both updates and creates a dynamic number of products.

Recommendations and solutions are much appricatates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: question is offtopic for this site

Comment: Look for https://prestashop.butikki.dk/en/home/14-import-fast.html for me the best import tool for .csv files. First import will only add new products, second import will update all data with prices and quantities

Comment: And the main concern is that products even its not available anymore in supplier must be in the csv file because if missing update will not notice that and will think that products are still available. So You will import products and not even noticed that some of the products are missing from the file and its still available in Your offer. You will noticed when customer buy this product and You will be not able to order from supplier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, i would recommend updating to a higher PS version.

Secondly there are enough 'free' modules that could help you, but in overall this is mainly a server issue, because out of the box Prestashop is able to handle the product updates quite nicely.